# Increase row by 1

Tags: excel, vba

I want the VBA code to use the value from B1 and present the result in A1, then the VBA code uses the value from B2 and presents the result in A2.

It works for B1 as I get the value in A1. I visible see the cursor on the excel sheet move down the B column, but nothing changes in the A column for results, not even the A1 cell is being overwritten.

It seems that the changing of rows works. However, the code isn't updating to utilize other cells in column A to post results.

This code is pulling an email address from B1, using the LDAP VBA function to make an inquiry of an active directory, and then returning the DisplayName of the member of the email into cell A1.

[image]

```
 Range("B1").Select
      ' Set Do loop to stop when an empty cell is reached.
      Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value = gigIDldap(4, True, Range("B1")) <--A1 will have the value from the gigID1dap VBA function using the value listed in B1
   ' Insert your code here.
         ' Step down 1 row from present location.
         ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
      Loop

' ******This didn't work. It gave a type mismatch error
For Each Row In ActiveSheet.Rows
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value = Row.Value
      For Each cell In Values
          ValueCell = Range("B1")
      Next cell
Next Row
   End Sub
```

Comment: Your code resets the range every time in the first line of the loop, which means that you're starting at the same place every single time.

Comment: Is there a way to make the function apply to A2 and B2, and A3 and B3 and so on until the bottom of the table?

Comment: A search for `excel vba iterate rows` turns up many results, such as https://stackoverflow.com/a/36828667/62576

Comment: For Each Row In ActiveSheet.Rows
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value = Row.Value
      For Each cell In Values
          ValueCell = Range("B1")
      Next cell
Next Row
   End Sub

This just gave me a type mismatch error

Comment: Also, what is the VBA data type for email addresses?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
Dim r As Long 'row pointer
With ActiveSheet
    For r = 1 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row 'loop from row 1 to last used cell in column B
        .Cells(r, 1).Value = gigIDldap(4, True, .Cells(r, 2).Value) 'write to column 1 with result from column 2
    Next
End With
```